# NixOS test with local network/internet access

Tags: testing, networking, sandbox, nix, nixos

I have a `flake.nix` with some `checks`, one of which needs to pull some resources from outside the testing environment (internet, local network) during the run of the test. However, the tests run in a sandbox, preventing access to the outside network (the internet, and the local network).

**The question is**: Is it possible to configure a check, or the machine(s) used within a check, to allow access to the outside network? How?

**Example**

```
# flake.nix
{
  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = "nixpkgs/nixos-22.11";
    flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";
  };

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachSystem
      (with flake-utils.lib.system; [ x86_64-linux ])
      (system:
        let
          pkgs = import nixpkgs {
            inherit system;
          };
        in
        {
          checks.test = pkgs.nixosTest {
            name = "test";
            nodes.n1 = { };
            testScript = ''
              n1.succeed("ping -c 1 8.8.8.8")  # ping google's DNS
            '';
          };

          formatter = pkgs.nixpkgs-fmt;
        }
      );
}
```

When run with `nix flake check` (in the same directory as the `flake.nix`), the test (correctly) fails on the ping with `` Exception: command `ping -c 1 8.8.8.8` failed (exit code 2) ``. I would like it succeed. (How) can I achieve that?

**Note**: I know that interacting with resources outside the testing environment is a bad practice, I'm fully aware of that. I would like to do it anyway, at my own risk.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the sandbox for the build by setting `__noChroot = true;` in your derivation.

That’s easy for a derivation, not so much for a NixOS test, where you would also need to change the network configuration of the VMs.
But if a derivation is all you need, that’s fine.

The other way to get network access is making a fixed-output derivation (FOD), by specifying the output hash – but that’s probably not what you want for tests.

More explanation on `__noChroot` here: https://zimbatm.com/notes/nix-packaging-the-heretic-way